# How to use "write" to get the information in a for each loop

Tags: java

Im currently working on a project at school, where I am to switch out a certain word in an ArrayList. The word is written several times in the list. Im going to change it with a random word from a different ArrayList. My loop currently works as I wanted to, surly I can make it better, but it works atm. The word im changing is "ADJEKTIV"

My problem is that I cant get it to write to a file. It will print out using the System.out.println to terminal, but the assignment tell us to write it to the file.

```
public class StoryCreator
{
    private InputReader reader;
    private OutputWriter writer;
    private Random random;

public StoryCreator()
{
    reader = new InputReader();
    writer = new OutputWriter();
    random = new Random();
}


public void createAdjectiveStory(String storyFilename, String adjectivesFilename, String outputFilename)
    {

        ArrayList<String> storyWords = reader.getWordsInFileWithScanner(storyFilename);

        ArrayList<String> adjectives = reader.getWordsInFileWithScanner(adjectivesFilename);

        String replaceKeyword = "ADJEKTIV";

        for(String words : storyWords)
        {
            if(storyWords.contains("ADJEKTIV"))
            {
                int adjectiveNumber = random.nextInt(adjectives.size());
                String randAdjective = adjectives.get(adjectiveNumber);

                String story = words.replace(replaceKeyword,randAdjective);

                System.out.println(story);
                writer.write(storyWords, outputFilename);
            }

        }



    }
```

I've gotten the text to be written in a file, but it doesn't write the file where I have replaced the words I want. It writes the file before the words are changed.

The output writer class

```
public class OutputWriter
```

{

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class OutputWriter
 */
public OutputWriter()
{
}

/**
 * Writes a list of words to a file. The words are separated by the 'space' character.
 * 
 * @param  output   the list of words
 * @param  filename   the name of the output file
 */
public void write(ArrayList<String> output, String filename)
{
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filename);
        for(String word : output) {
            out.write(word + " ");
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error writing output file: " + exc);
    }

}
```

}

Hope someone knows how I can manage this.

Comment: did you use `FileOutputStream` ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have two classes with an input writer, and output wiriter. But I guess more advanced programmers than my self can see that just by looking at the code.


public class StoryCreator
{
    private InputReader reader;
    private OutputWriter writer;
    private Random random;

    public StoryCreator()
    {
        reader = new InputReader();
        writer = new OutputWriter();
        random = new Random();
    }

Here is the top part of my code

Comment: What is your `writer.write` Please add your addition comment/code to the question and not as a comment.

Comment: No I have not used that, we havent learned about it sadly.. the Output writer and input writer was made by the teacher, and our job was just to use the storycreater class.

Comment: Rather than commenting `I forgot to mention` post it in your question

Comment: Your `writer.write()` is outside the for each loop, and the variable `story` is out of scope. It can't be compiled actually.

Comment: Do I need to post the other classes aswell? Im farily new to both porgramming, and how much information needed for others to see what's wrong with a code.

Comment: It looks like you can solve this by using `writer.write(story, outputFilename);` , but it is not clear. What is your current problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through `String word : storyWords` and replacing the `word` object with the random word. So, far so good.

The problem I think you have is here:

```
String story = words.replace(replaceKeyword,randAdjective);

System.out.println(story);
writer.write(storyWords, outputFilename);
```

You write out the `story` object using `System.out.println(story)` but then you write out the `storyWords` object to the file. This `storyWords` list will include the old `String` as you haven't replaced it with `story` (Which has the replacement in). This is why you are seeing the old word when writing to a file.

This brings up a new issue of the replacement of the String in `storyWords` as trying to modify within a for-each loop will throw an exception.

I think it would be better to use a normal `for loop` instead of a `for-each` to keep the position of the String inside `storyWords` so you can make the replace.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < storyWords.size() ; i++)
{
    String word = storyWords.get(i);
    if(word.contains("ADJEKTIV"))
    {
        int adjectiveNumber = random.nextInt(adjectives.size());
        String randAdjective = adjectives.get(adjectiveNumber);

        String story = word.replace(replaceKeyword, randAdjective);

        System.out.println(story);

        storyWords.set(i, story);

        writer.write(storyWords, outputFilename);
    }
}
```

I think that should be the kind of thing you are looking for.

I have kept the code as close as possible to what you had originally written.

I did change the `storyWords.contains("ADJEKTIV")` to `word.contains("ADJEKTIV")` making the assumption that is what you meant.

Comment: Note: I have not run this block

Comment: Thank you, kind Sir! This worked perfectly! thank you so mcuh!